# Showing 2D shapes on top of texture in OpenGL

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, opencv

I'm capturing webcam data using OpenCV and display them as the Texture for a GL Window, **This works fine.**

```
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, image->width, image->height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->imageData);
```

But I want also to overlay some basic shapes, Md2 models on top of this, retaining the texture in the background and in the same window itself.

This is my function that is passed into `glutDisplayFunc()`

```
void drawScene() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // Set Projection Matrix
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT, 0);

    // Setup the view  // Switch to Model View Matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
    // Trapezoid
    glVertex3f(-0.7f, -1.5f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.7f, -1.5f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.4f, -0.5f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(-0.4f, -0.5f, -5.0f);
    glEnd(); //End quadrilateral coordinates

    // start drawing the Background texture
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

**EDIT**
new order

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS); //Begin quadrilateral coordinates
    // Trapezoid
    glVertex3f(-0.7f, -1.5f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.7f, -1.5f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.4f, -0.5f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(-0.4f, -0.5f, -5.0f);
    glEnd(); //End quadrilateral coordinates
```

**EDIT:**
New order and coordinates:

```
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
// Trapezoid to be displayed on top of texture
glVertex3f(0.2f, 0.3f, -0.6f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex3f(0.4f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex3f(-0.4f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
glEnd(); //End quadrilateral coordinates
////
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // start drawing the background texture 
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
glEnd();
```

The result after doing above and Disabling `gluOrtho2D()`

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what is wrong? All I see is a working program that needs some extra code to load and display models.

Comment: +1 for the instant reply. All i get is the background texture, those 2D shapes are not visible. That's all. :)

Comment: Ah, you are drawing the background texture AFTER drawing the trapezoid. Hence it is drawing over them. Reverse the drawing order and it should work.

Comment: Changed. but it's still the same :(

Comment: Added the new order above. But no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs for [`gluOrtho2D()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml):

> gluOrtho2D sets up a two-dimensional orthographic viewing region.  This is equivalent to calling glOrtho with near = -1 and far = 1.

You're placing your trapezoid at Z = -5, way behind your near clipping plane:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(-0.7f, -1.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(0.7f, -1.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(0.4f, -0.5f, -5.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.4f, -0.5f, -5.0f);
glEnd();
```

Try -0.5 for your Z coordinates, or at least something between -1 and 0.

**EDIT:** Example:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

int win_w = 0;
int win_h = 0;
GLuint texObj = 0;

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // set up projection
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    double halfWidth = (win_w / 2.0);;
    double halfHeight = (win_h / 2.0);
    glOrtho( -halfWidth, halfWidth, -halfHeight, halfHeight, -10, 10 );

    // set up modelview
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // render textured quad
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glColor3ub(255,255,255);
    glPushMatrix();
        glScalef(halfWidth * 0.9, halfHeight * 0.9, 1.0);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0,0);
            glVertex2f(-1,-1);
            glTexCoord2f(1,0);
            glVertex2f(1,-1);
            glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            glVertex2f(1,1);
            glTexCoord2f(0,1);
            glVertex2f(-1,1);
        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // draw quad on top
    glColor3ub(255,0,0);
    glPushMatrix();
        // move quad back a bit so it's above Z=0
        glTranslatef(0,0,-1);
        glScalef(50,50,50);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex2f(-1,-1);
            glVertex2f(1,-1);
            glVertex2f(1,1);
            glVertex2f(-1,1);
        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    win_w = w;
    win_h = h;
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

GLuint getTexture()
{
    // 2x2 texture
    unsigned char bytes[] =
    {
          0,   0, 255,      255, 255, 255,
        255,   0,   0,      0, 255,   0,
    };

    GLuint texID;
    glGenTextures(1, &texID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bytes);
    return texID;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
    glutCreateWindow("Texture");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

    texObj = getTexture();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the info and suggestion. After doing what you've said I ended up with the above result. Please have a look at the screenshot under my edited section.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The texture is upside down I'll try to fix that!

Comment: Would you mind sharing your sources? I'd like to know where I went wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to disable texturing (`glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`) if you're drawing things that shouldn't be textured like your trapezoid.

Otherwise the last set texture coordinate will apply to all your new vertices, sampling your texture in some strange spot.

Comment: It doen't work either. I tried calling glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) before Trapezoid and glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) before  glTexCoord2f() lines of Texture. It still shows only the texture.

Comment: @coder9: Make sure you call it _outside_ of a glBegin(…)–glEnd() block. BTW: You shouldn't use immediate mode (glBegin(…)–glEnd() that is) anyway. It's outdated and slow.  Also there's little use in using gluBuild2DMipmaps, since OpenGL-2 you can use arbitrary dimensions for texture images. Just disable mipmaping and only upload level 0.

Comment: @datenwolf hi. what do you mean by `only upload level 0` ? can you pls post some skeletal code?

Comment: Instead of `gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, image->width, image->height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->imageData);` do `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB,image->width, image->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->imageData); glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);` level is the 2nd parameter of glTexImage2D.